# Specifying a TVS to protect against inductive spikes

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, transient, tvs, transient-suppression

I'm choosing a transient voltage suppressor to absorb the freewheeling current from a 1mH inductor in the rare situation the output of a SMPS is disconnected during load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy6C6U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The maximum output current is 6A and I have chosen a TVS with a maximum clamping voltage of 602 volts. ([The 1.5KE440CA*](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/LFSI/LFSI-S-A0011484030/LFSI-S-A0011484030-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0)) On the TVS datasheet the maximum peak pulse current is specified at 3.1 amps for a 10/1000us test waveform. Can I use this part safely in knowledge that the pulse width in my application is much shorter (10us for 6A to ramp down to 0A based on my calculations)?

The reason I think it may be safe is because in the datasheet the Peak Pulse Power Rating for a 10us pulse is 15kW. The peak power at the start of the my pulse (6A across the 602V clamp will be a measly 3.6kW)

Comment: I'm not understanding the circuit you have drawn. Your best bet is to simulate and examine the total number of joules absorbed.

Comment: When SW1 opens the voltage spike will be clamped by the TVS. Ignore D3, C1, V2 - I realize they are confusing. It's not really the sort of thing I can simulate because the question is regarding the stress capabilities of TVS diodes

Comment: Of course you can use a simulator for calculating the stress.

Comment: Something is odd here. What SMPS has a 1mH 6A output inductor and no filter capacitor afterwards? Have you misinterpreted a CMC perhaps? Is this a current sourcing SMPS? (In which case, the load should be switched off with a short, not an open!) And what is V2-C1-D3 doing?

Comment: It's for a grid connected inverter project I'm working on (https://www.instructables.com/Grid-Tie-Inverter-V5/). I shouldn't have drawn in V2-C1-D3, here's the pdf of the actual schematic (https://content.instructables.com/F9F/FXGI/LFTZ7UQI/F9FFXGILFTZ7UQI.pdf).

Comment: So you want to protect the K2 relay contact? What if Q4 is still conducting?